# Rails 4 Initializer Not Loading

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to put my emailer password in a .yml file.

Under `config/initializers` I have a file `emailers_config.rb`

```
require 'yaml'
EMAIL_CONFIG = YAML.load(File.read(Rails.root + "config/mailer_config.yml"))
```

and in my `config/mailer_config.yml` I have:

```
#production password
smtp_password_pro: foo
#devevopment env password
smtp_password_dev: bar
```

Now it seems My initializes is not running, because I get this `uninitialized constant EMAIL_CONFIG (NameError)`

Now Rails is supposed to laod everything under the initializers folder, so loading the file is not an issue.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the answer to your question but I can recommend another method

Passwords can be stored easier to `.env` file
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbcAO.png]

like this

```
#Root dir create file ".env"
PASSWORD=123456
```

and load password

```
#Somewhere in app
ENV['PASSWORD'] #=> 123456
```

it works I hope will help you

[image]

Comment: no i mean the result I get is nil, it is not loading the file

Comment: yes because you try `ENV[:symbol]` and you need string `ENV['string']`

Comment: same. Now, ENV['SMTP_PRO_PASS'] gives me nil

Comment: yes in root your application, create file '.env' and past text `SMTP_PRO_PASS=12345` open you rails console and `ENV['SMTP_PRO_PASS']` file can start whit dot and be invisible

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42273/discussion-between-monk-code-and-trt-trt)

Answer (score 3):

If you are having trouble accessing a constant in your YAML file, try shutting down your local server with `control + c`, then run:

```
$ spring stop
```

Boot up your server or console again:

`$ rails [server | console]`

And you might have access to that constant.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your **config/mailer_config.yml**:

```
  development:
    smtp_password: foo
  production:
    smtp_password: bar
```

And then, in **emailers_config.rb**:

```
  EMAIL_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/mailer_config.yml")[Rails.env]
```

Now, you will get your password for every env, using:

```
  EMAIL_CONFIG['smtp_password']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:
ENGINE_CONFIG = YAML.load(File.read(File.join(Rails.root, "config/subfolder", "engine.yml")))[Rails.env]